# ElasticSearch can't get the TransPortClient when connect the local env

Tags: elasticsearch

When i use the TransPortClient method to create the ElasticSearch client. 
The code is like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // ES config
    Settings settings = settingsBuilder()
            .put("cluster.name", "dev-application")
            .put("client.transport.sniff", true)
            .build();
    // ES client
    try {
        TransportClient client = TransportClient.builder().settings(settings).build()
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 9300));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("print");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("print");
}
```

But i get the error info show below:

```
01:32:09.288 [main] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.client.transport - [Magilla] node_sampler_interval[5s]
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:54569', transport: 'socket'
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: (
  class: org/jboss/netty/channel/socket/nio/NioWorkerPool, 
  method: newWorker signature(Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;)Lorg/jboss/netty/channel/socket/nio/AbstractNioWorker;) 
  Wrong return type in function
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.createClientBootstrap(NettyTransport.java:349)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.doStart(NettyTransport.java:277)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:68)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.doStart(TransportService.java:170)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:68)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient$Builder.build(TransportClient.java:159)
    at com.dmall.dms.fastdelivery.service.parser.SimpleParserServiceTest.main(SimpleParserServiceTest.java:26)
```

i can't understand how this happen, can someone ever meet this problem?? thanks!!!

Comment: You seem to have a dependency conflict with Netty classes coming from two different JARs, JBoss ones and Elasticsearch ones. Are you using Spark by any chance? If yes, you need to exclude the `org.jboss.netty`package.

Comment: i check the jar ,and find that i use the two different netty jar,so i remove the jboss one ,and it fixed. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have a dependency conflict with Netty classes coming from two different JARs, JBoss ones and Elasticsearch ones.

if that's the case, you need to exclude the JBoss one, i.e. org.jboss.nettypackage and you should be good.

Comment: What do you mean by "exclude". How do i exclude?